# Sweet alert not triggering my php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am using sweet alerts 2 for my webpage and i am trying to trigger my php file when the user presses delete on the sweet alert, if they do not do nothing. For some odd reason it is not triggering the php file, the pop does not come up either, i ran a simple sweet alert in the console just to see if i have the correct scripts in and it works fine.
 I have this code so far :

```
   <form method="post" id="deleteF" name="delete">
        <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-xl btn-mrg" id="delete" >Delete</button>
   </form>

$(document).on('submit', 'deleteF', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You can not recover your account if you delete!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Delete",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    },
    function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'lib/delete.php',
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    swal("NOT Deleted!", "Something happened!", "error");
                }
            });
        } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Your account was not deleted", "error");
        }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

My php file only has a simple echo in it just to for testing, any help would be greatly appreciated, Note i only included the relevant parts, the sweet alert section is enclosed in script tags

Comment: Has nothing to do with the alert code, your event listener is wrong. `$(document).on('submit', 'deleteF', function (e) {` You say you have a `< deleteF>` tag. Add the missing `#`

Comment: Hi, thanks the pop up shows now however it is not firing the php for some reason, i checked the console and i get several warnings telling me there is a unknown parameter " sweetalert2.all.js:141 SweetAlert2: Unknown parameter "closeOnConfirm " ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a data-id='" . $rows['id'] . "' id='delete_id' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' href='javascript:void(0)'></span>delete</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#delete_id', function(e) {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            SwalDelete(id);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    function SwalDelete(id) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "It will be deleted permanently!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            preConfirm: function() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                    $.ajax({
                            url: 'office_info_delete.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: 'id=' + id,
                            dataType: 'json'
                        })
                        .done(function(response) {
                            Swal.fire('Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted.', 'success')
                        })
                        .fail(function() {
                            Swal.fire('Oops...', 'Something went wrong with ajax !', 'error')
                        });
                });
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add a description to your answer!